# 404 ao tentar acessar url post com springboot

Tags: angularjs, post, spring-boot, retrofit

Boa noite, tenho o código abaixo com a implementação de um serviço rest /teste123, e ao chamar esse método a partir do código angular-js, já autenticado com a autenticação básica do spring-boot eu tenho acesso a esse serviço.
Quando tento acessar ele a partir do retrofit2 do meu android ou da extensão postman do chrome, os dois dão erro 404.
Alguém me explica oque estou fazendo de errado.
Só para deixar claro que estou apontando para o ip correto do pc que é 192.168.... e não para localhost no momento das chamadas.
Obrigado.

```
@RestController
public class TesteController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/teste123", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Programa gravaLote2(@RequestBody Programa programa) {
    System.out.println(programa);
    return new Programa();
} 
}
```

abaixo o exemplo do código em angular-js que funciona.

```
$http.post("/teste123", {id: 'asd', txtPrograma: 'adsadasd'})
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
```

Aqui a interface que usei no android.

```
public interface ExecucaoService {

@POST("teste123")
public Call<Programa> gravaLote(@Body Programa programa);}
```

e para adicionar as credenciais no header do retrofit fiz da seguinte forma.

```
        private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrlWS)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        String credentials = username + ":" + password;
        final String basic = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", basic)
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .method(original.method(), original.body());
                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
      OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
    // retrofit.create(serviceClass); aqui pego a instancia do serviço criada.
```

aqui a imagem mostrando o sucesso do angular na esquerda e o problema na direita.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu ainda tenho esperança que não é problema do retrofit nem do postman, e sim de uma configuração que não fiz no sptring-boot.

Comment: Pessoal, não resolvi o problema com o spring-boot-security, removi ele do projeto e implementei um filter de segurança básico, apenas para atestar que tem sessão ou não tem sessão e desisti de achar o real problema. Com certeza é alguma situação que o spring-security não conseguia pegar o header Authentication e efetuar o login com ele. Já que o projeto é um TCC e não vai para a internet tão cedo, vou deixar para me preocupar com isso mais a frente. Mas se alguém souber me dizer o problema para que eu volte a utilizar o spring eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a documentação do spring-boot, para você criar uma aplicação web básica, você só precisa do parent do spring-boot e a dependência spring-boot-starter-web. O erro mais comum que acontecia comigo no inicio do meu aprendizado com o spring-boot, era em relação ao header errado que era enviado na requisição, mas isso me causava um 400 ou 405. Não tenho muita experiência com android mas pelo que eu pude notar, esse trecho que código (@POST("execucao/gravaLote")) indica que você está mandando um post para o endereço execucao/gravaLote e que pode estar causando o erro 404, pois o seu endereço é /teste123. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Você fez a observação correta, eu editei algumas vezes o código e não mantive integridade entre essas classes aqui no post.
Não consegui testar um filtro para permitir CORS ainda, mas o problema esta quando adiciono o spring-security na jogada. Vou corrigir ali em cima pra não deixar dúvidas.

Comment: Sobre CORS, você pode fazer isso de uma maneira bem simples com o que o spring-boot já oferece. Por exemple veja essa sessão da documentação (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-cors), que explica como fazer. Isso se você estiver usando uma versão recente do spring-boot, é claro. Sobre o spring-security, qual é sua dúvida com ele realmente? Só entendi que quando você o adiciona no seu projeto, você está recebendo 404. Como você está configurando ele no seu projeto? seria bom mais detalhes de como você faz isso.